# I want to replace HTML tags but keep the text in between

Tags: regex

I want to replace the HTML tags but keep the text in between.
Find: `<span class="Heading3-strong">.*?</span>`
Replace: `<strong>.*?</strong>`
It seems as if something is wrong in the middle...

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/372239 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/372239

Comment: (Since my post was deleted, let's try as a comment.)  Using regex to process any kind of nested markup is a **very bad idea**.  If you're not careful, Tony the Pony will come for you.

See also [the legendary post over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which program you are using the regex in, but what you're looking for are [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html).

For example, in Notepad++, the following would work:

**Find:**

```
<span class="Heading3-strong">(.*?)</span>
```

**Replace with:**

```
<strong>\1</strong>
```

The `\1` is a back reference to the first capturing group (the part between `(` and `)`) in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

My previous post was deleted, so let me try again, with more detail.

In all seriousness, **do not use regex on nested markup**.  It's a recipe for pain.

Although Glorfindel's example works for simple cases, it will fail whenever you run into nested tag sets.

**Works:**

```html
<span class="Heading3-strong">this is text</span>
```

... becomes:

```html
<strong>this is text</strong>
```

This is still well-formed and valid markup.

**However, this doesn't work:**

```html
<span class="Heading3-strong">this is text <span style="color:red;">with</span> <span style="color:blue;">additional</span> <span style="color:green;">tags</span> in the middle</span>
```

... becomes:

```html
<strong>this is text <span style="color:red;">with</strong> <span style="color:blue;">additional</span> <span style="color:green;">tags</span> in the middle</span>
```

This is now **malformed** markup.

This is an intractable problem for simple regex -- there's just no way to handle nested markup correctly with regex alone.  If you need to change tag pairs in any sort of nested tag content, your best bet is to use a tool specifically geared towards markup, such as XSLT or something similar.